# LINQ to entity, sort the subset of returned values

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

```
        var myView = await _context.foo
            .Include(p => p.subFoos)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FooID == id);
```

This code returns a row from the database and the linked sub rows held in the collection `subFoos`, what I'd like to do is order the collection rather than have them displayed in table order. I've got a field `OrderBy` but I can't figure out how to use it.

```
        var myView = await _context.foo
            .Include(p => p.subFoos)
                .OrderBy(x => x.OrderBy)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FooID == id);
```

This orders by the top level row, rather than the collection. How do I apply `OrderBy` to the collection.
Thanks

Comment: Why not just query the Subfoos directly Include(a=>a.Foo).Where(subFoo.Foo.FooId=id  )  that will make SubFoos the root object and OrderBy will sort them . you can gram Foo object from any of the results as they are all from the same Foo parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get any of the above to work so just retrieved the data using

```
var myView  = await _context.foo
.Include(p => p.subFoos)
.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FooID == id);
```

then ordered the `myView.subFoos` by converting them to a List

```
myView.subFoos = myView.subFoos.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.OrderBy).ToList();
```

Only one database call, works nicely.